# How can i login to Azure with Powershell using 2 factor authentication?

Tags: azure, powershell, cicd

I am logging into Azure from Powershell using the following commands, but since 2 factor authentication was enabled I get the error below:

```
az login -u testemail@testserver.com -p "<mypassword>"
az account set --subscription "<my_subscription>"
```

But I get the error:

AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a
new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access the subscription.

There is 2 factor authentication configured here and if i login with the browser it pops up the windows to enter the security code. How can i automate that within Powershell or is there any other option ?
Reason being I run automated scripts within a CI/CD pipeline and am trying to avoid any user interaction .

Comment: Reach out to your Identity team and request a service account that is unaffected by 2FA. They probably have a solution for these kind of requirements, such as group with limited interactive login, stronger password policy, etc.

Comment: So basically if you use 2FA it requires human interaction no other way ?

Comment: Correct, that's the whole point behind 2FA.

Comment: Are you sure, that you need an actual user account to perform your tasks? You can also login with azure cli using a service principle that has the necessary RBAC permission on your subscription (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli).

Comment: Service principal can be used but it still requires to used credentials via a command line window in jenkins that im trying to avoid